# Book has spacegates that a person can walk across

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to identify the name of a book that involved a civilization that utilized spacegates to instantly travel across space, literally stepping from one world to another. In the book, a family home could have different rooms located throughout the galaxy and the people simply walked through the doorway to move from room to room (and planet to planet)

Comment: I know I've read several books with that. You'll need to narrow it down some more. What else do you remember?

Comment: Closing because the question never got improved, and it's merely accumulating 'me too' answers.

Answer (score 27):

My best guess would be *Hyperion* and *The Fall of Hyperion* by Dan Simmons, if your "spacegates" were called farcasters in the book.

Comment: I would second this one

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Although I seem to remember them getting a lot more attention in the sequels Endymion and The Rise of Endymion.

Comment: Yes definitely the Hyperion series. Especially the one house with many 'spacegates' (farcasters) seems correct. There where also big farcasters to have a river run over multiple worlds.

Comment: From Hyperion page 206 [I kept my home, adding six rooms on five worlds...](http://books.google.com/books?id=aP1load_NsIC&pg=PA200&dq=dan+simmons+farcaster+home&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XiwPT8rjGqrX0QHI_5WXAw&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 6):

Harry Harrison's ["One Step From Earth"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Step_from_Earth) is a collection of short stories exploring the discovery and use of a "portal system".  While the first story is more "hard" in trying to explain the uses of the technology, the remain eight are more "soft" and concerned with how the technology changes society and people.  I distinctly remember a man fleeing from a crime he had just committed, skipping across many worlds in an attempt to lose his persuer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, perhaps describe how exactly it matches the details in the question?

Answer (score 4):

Probably not what you are thinking of, but in the Ringworld books, the Puppeteers used teleporters called 'stepping discs' - you step onto it and it teleported you to another location. They seemed to be mostly for local use, though.

Answer (score 3):

Pandora's Star by Peter. F. Hamilton uses portal technology to step between worlds, but the general application was Train stations, not individual rooms. But it is a good example of this technological mechanic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember a similar technology being used in The Dosadi Experiment by Frank Herbert, I'm not sure if it was used in the book before it, Whipping Star.

Comment: They were called Taprisiots if I recall correctly.

Comment: You're thinking about the Caleban's S'eye gates.  The Taprisiots were just communicators.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar mechanism, initially presented as a natural phenomenon but later revealed to be perhaps technological in origin, in Doris Piserchia's "Spaceling". It's not the book you're thinking of, in part because the portals drift and can be unpredictable, but if you're interested in the theme you may like it.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, the James H. Schmitz Telzey Amberdon story "The Lion Game" has a world where most "buildings" are actually groups of rooms in various locations connected by portals and are not actual buildings as we know them. The heroine ends up trapped in a hotel called the Luraal where some of the portals are traps. She is trying to deal with hostile aliens and escape the building.